# Call unsubscribe with REDIS

Tags: c#, redis

I am using REDIS.

I need to use unsubscribe in Redis.
I am using ServiceStack for C#: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis

I copied the code of: http://docs.servicestack.net/redis-client/redis-pubsub

When doing subscribe there is infinite lock, so what I did is doing subscribe in thread.

I can do unsubscribe, but not with unsubscribe method. This is done fine with:

```
myThread.abort();
... // + sending just a publish message.
```

but I need to do that with unsubscribe method.

```
 subscription.UnSubscribeFromAllChannels(); // ****Not like that***

// Not wanting doing like above as the example on the second link, 
// but need to do as following:
     subsciption.unsubscribe(new string[] {"MyChannel"});
unfortunely, the above just doesn't work at all (no unsubscribe).
```

I didn't see any example on web and I need to call unsubscribe not as same as the second link example ,which checked out:

```
if (++messagesReceived == PublishMessageCount) etc.)
```

How can I do unsubscribe using the method subsciption.unsubscribe as I described in this post?

Comment: Have you tried just `subscription.Unsubscribe("MyChannel")`? Not sure why you are turning it into an array? You shouldn't be having lock-up issues, but you can issue "fire and forget" commands, like `subscription.Unsubscribe("MyChannel", null, CommandFlags.FireAndForget)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Subscribe* API's will block the current thread. Once subscribed the callbacks execute messages on the same thread as the subscription. You'll also need to call unsubscribe with the same subscription on the same thread.

Rather than using Redis Pub/Sub API's directly it's [easier to just use RedisPubSubServer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#new-managed-pubsub-server) which manages the subscription in a background thread for you.

Comment: O.K, thank you.
Nevertheless - How can I call unsubcribe method, or adding another event as the event on link http://docs.servicestack.net/redis-client/redis-pubsub - solving the problem in either the orignal way, or the way as you suggested? Please give me examples for unsubscribe for both ways (using Redis Pub/Sub directly or using RedisPubSubServer).

Thanks :)

Comment: @Eitan You just need to call `RedisPubSubServer.Stop()`. Have a look at [how RedisPubSubServer unsubscribes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisPubSubServer.cs#L267) i.e. it issues a "Stop" command which unsubscribes from the subscription in the callback.

Comment: I presume RedisPubSubServer.stop() do Thread.abort().
I did thread.abort either.

I don't understand - why there is the unsubscribe method if I cannot use it? I wonder whether one succeeded doing that for old fashion classes. What if I have lot of code over that class - I am curious how that was solved out, if ever.

Thanks :)

Comment: @Eitan RedisPubSubServer does use the UnSubscribe API, it just needs to be called on the thread that made the subscription, i.e. in the message callback. [Thread.Abort is only used as a last resort](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisPubSubServer.cs#L435), i.e it first waits for the thread to finish gracefully after it's unsubscribed.

Comment: Thank you!
I will check that out.